# parameter handed from ready() to function

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, ready

I got this code snippet from an image uploader:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {e.preventDefault();}));
});
```

(I set the last brackets by myself). I am new to jQuery and I am wondering what the "e" stands for? Is "e" a variable handed from ready() to the function?

Comment: The `e` is a **[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)**.

Comment: @Zakaria: No, it really isn't (not the one passed to `ready`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `e`s in your snippet, and they're different.

The `e` passed to the `ready` callback is a reference to the `jQuery`/`$` function.

The `e` passed to the callback on the `submit` event is an `Event` object.

This is all covered [by the documentation](http://api.jquery.com): [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready), [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: (1) what do you mean by jQuery/$ function? (2) with ready-callback you mean the function that is executed inside the ready method?
(3) Is it true that in both cases the methods ready() and on() are responsible for which (and which type of) variable is passed to the callbacks (i.e. the heandlers)?

Comment: @NickelPaulsen: I suggest reading through the jQuery documentation. (1) When I say "the `jQuery`/`$` function," I mean that literally: http://api.jquery.com/jquery (2) Yes, "the X callback" is standard shorthand for "the callback function passed into the X function." (3) Yes, exactly right.